# Reading documents in .NET

Tags: c#, text, document, .doc

Can I open any file formats with Word interop that Microsoft Word itself supports?

My task looks very simple, I need to read text, only text, from any type of documents commonly used (to compare the documents based on content). Is there a way I can do this easier than the above mentioned Word Iterop? Are there any *free* libraries to do this? Or to open *any* (.doc, .docx, .pdf, .rtf, openoffice docs, etc.) document types? I'm busy looking, but haven't found too many solutions yet, and I can't afford studying the 800-page specifications of all the formats.

P.S.: Handling pdf separately is OK, as well as having libraries for all the types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a new framework called Toxy. The goal of it is to extract data/text from various documents like what you mentioned. The first release will be available early next year.(maybe Feb.) You can find some implementation here: https://github.com/tonyqus/toxy. But it's not ready for now.